# Filter by date with group by condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table that I want to group by id and filter by date.

```
StudentTable
DateTime StudentId Grade

SELECT DateTime, StudentId, AVG(Grade)
FROM StudentTable
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DateTime, 102) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, '11-1-2018', 102) 
AND CONVERT(DATE, '12-02-2018', 102)
GROUP BY StudentId
```

But this gives me error:

> Column 'DateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

What should I do?

Comment: @DaleBurrell Both the filtered and the group

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem. But if you have better solution please let me know.

```
SELECT StudentId, AVG (Grade) FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM StudentTable
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DateTime, 102) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, '11-1-2018', 102) 
    AND CONVERT(DATE, '12-02-2018', 102)
) MainT
GROUP BY MainT.StudentId
```

Comment: As I said above, it depends how you want to aggregate date, you could use max(date) for example. It comes down to, if you want to average a grade over a period then you have to also aggregate the date in some meaningful way because each resulting row will be the result of multiple dates.